# Get a view of scheduled tasks excluding some TODO states on Org Mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode, gtd

Here are the todo states I use (on GNU Emacs 24.5.1):

```
(setq org-todo-keywords '((type "TODO" "NEXT" "DONE" "STARTED" "WAITING" "FROZEN" "REFERENCE" "CANCELLED" "DELEGATED")))
```

I would like to create a custom view showing all the scheduled tasks for the current week (next 8 days) that have  TODO, NEXT, STARTED, WAITING, FROZEN, REFERENCE, or DELEGATED as a todo state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
  '(("8" "Scheduled this week" 
     ((agenda "" 
       ((org-agenda-start-day "+0")
        (org-agenda-span 8)        
        (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'todo '("DONE" "CANCELLED")))
       )
     ))
   ))
)
```